# Replace character in textfield on keydown

Tags: javascript, html

I have a textarea, when I press Enter I need to insert a custom {br} tag instead of wrap the text on a new line. I have solved the wrap issue with CSS, the problem is that when I press enter the tag is inserted at the end of the string. How can I insert it in the same position of the input?

**HTML**

```
<textarea class="form-control d-inline-block ml-3 my-auto" rows="1" value="" onkeydown="tagOnInput(this, window.event.keyCode)"></textarea>
```

**CSS**

```
textarea[rows="1"] {
    overflow: auto;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

**JS**

```
function tagOnInput(textField, key){
  if (key === 13) {
      textField.value = textField.value + "{br}"; // Tag is added at the end, but should be in the cursor position.
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `textField.selectionStart` and `textField.selectionEnd` to get the cursor position. Then use `substring()` to extract the two parts of the String, and concatenate the two with `{br}` in between

```js
const el = document.getElementById("area")
const btn = document.getElementById("btn")

area.addEventListener('keydown', (e) => {
  if (e.which === 13) {
    e.preventDefault()
    const selectionStart = el.selectionStart
    const selectionEnd = el.selectionEnd
    const value = el.value
    const toInsert = '{br}'

    const partLeft = value.substr(0, selectionStart)
    const partRight = value.substr(selectionEnd)

    el.value = partLeft + toInsert + partRight
    el.focus()
    el.selectionEnd = selectionEnd + toInsert.length
    el.selectionStart = selectionEnd + toInsert.length
  }
  
})
```

```html
<label>Textarea</label>
<textarea id="area"></textarea>
```

If the is not selecting text, this will insert at the cursor position. If he   is, this will replace the selected text by `{br}`

Comment: This works, however I got a weird behavior, when I press enter the tag is inserted but the cursor jumps at the end of the line (if I'm inserting a tag in the middle of the string).

Comment: @Artemis I updated the snippet with code that will move the cursor just after the inserted text and cancels the event so no line return is inserted

Answer (score 1):

You currently append your tag after the textField's value. Whatever is in your textField it'll always add it at the end.

You have to get your cursor's position, and insert your tag at this position in your textField's value, maybe using something like [javascript slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice) I guess.

[get cursor position in a textarea](https://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/282/how-to-get-the-current-cursor-position-and-selection-within-a-text-input-or-textarea-in-javascript)